# Прочитать файл по строкам в Spring Boot

Tags: java, input, spring-boot, io

Всем привет, хочу прочитать файл по строкам в Spring Boot приложении.
Написал такой код

```
private  List<String> ipAddress = new ArrayList<>();
private File file = new File("templates/BlackListIp.txt");
private Scanner scanner;
@Scheduled(fixedRate = 5000)
public void readAndAddToList(){

    {
        try {
            scanner = new Scanner(file);
            while (scanner.hasNextLine()){
                ipAddress.add(scanner.nextLine());
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Sorry! File not found");

        }

    }
```

Получается прохожусь по файлу и строки заношу в ArrayList. Но при отладке выходи, что файла не находит.
Как с этим быть?
Читал, что можно как-то с помощью загрузчика Spring

```
Resource resource  = 
  resourceLoader.getResource("classpath:\\templates\\BlackListIp.txt");
```

Но не пойму как тога прочитать по строкам
Подскажите пожалуйста

Comment: Boot тут вообще не при чём. Да и "загрузчик" к Spring не относится.

Comment: Тут слишком много может быть причин, какая именно у тебя?

Comment: Не видит путь как бы я не прописывал его